# GWT: how to create my own asynchronous methods?

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous

Is there a way to make my own asynchronous methods on GWT? I am using gwt 2.7 and seems like no java concurrency classes are compatible with gwt.

Here is my story. My client side has a service class, which caches some server data. It has a normal getter method(synchronous) to get the cached data, and it also has a reload method to update the cache.(of course, it is asynchronous). After reload request is sent, the getter method should be disabled until update is done.

Right now, each time I use the getter method, I wrap it inside a timer. It works fine, but I am wondering there is a better way to do it. It is too much boilerplate code.

```
    final AutoProgressMessageBox messageBox = 
            ServiceManager.createProgressMessage("Progress", "Loading Products...");
    Timer timer = new Timer(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!serviceManager.isProductLocked()){
                // already loaded
                serviceManager.getProducts();
                // do my work...
                messageBox.hide();
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT has the [`Scheduler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html) class, which allows you access some static methods that simulate a multithreaded environment. Specifically, you might be interested in the [`Scheduler.scheduleFixedPeriod`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFixedPeriod(com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand,%20int)) method:

> Schedules a repeating command that is scheduled with a constant delay. That is, the next invocation of the command will be scheduled for delayMs milliseconds after the last invocation completes.